# How to cluster by Zip Code - all locations within 100 miles

Tags: python, r, powerbi, cluster-analysis, zipcode

I have a database without about 700 records, each with their own zip code. I want to show the rows (by unique ID) that fall within a 100 mile cluster. I also have a zip code distance DB from the National Bureau of Economic Research (https://data.nber.org/distance/2022/100miles/). This file is quite large but looks like the table below.

```
zip1    miles_to_zip2    zip2
1534    50               1001
1534    44               1002
1534    48               1003
```

This data has 13m rows, but I really only need the distance for the zip codes in my database (about 700 different ones).

I can use Python, R, or Power BI to do this, depending on which is the simplest. How do I group all my unique IDs by a cluster group that identifies locations within 100 miles of each other? For reference, the data I want to analyze looks similar to the table below.

```
ID     ZipCode     Sales
1      15110       10,000
2      15115       15,000
3      98000       2,000
4      98001       10,000
5      70570       10,000
```

My goal is essentially to return a column called cluster that would assign ID 1 and 2 to cluster1 and ID 3 and 4 to cluster 2, and 5 to cluster 3 (based on the 100 mile criteria).

Comment: What clustering have you tried? K-means unfortunately requires you to know (about) how many clusters exist, but others (hclust, DBSCAN) have relaxed requirements in this regard.

Comment: Honestly I'm not super sure where to start. My goal is to basically show all my records that fall within a 100 mile range. The intent is to identify which of the locations can all be visited within a week or so.

Comment: I suggest using `dbscan::dbscan(X, eps=zz)` where you vary `zz` to approximate your 100-mile limit (perhaps it's just `zz=100`, not sure). Since `dbscan` accepts a "dist" object, you can likely take your `M`-row data and create an `M`-by-`M` distance matrix. FYI, your distance "database" (zip1, miles, zip2) appears to be corrupted, you likely need to use `colClasses=` to specify that the zips are strings, not numbers; it should never be a number, I recommend _against_ just 0-padding it post-read.

Comment: This seems poorly defined... if zipcode A is 75 miles from zip code B, and B is 75 miles from zipcode C, but the distance between A and C is 150 miles, how do you want the clustering?

Comment: I'll be attempting the dbscan above here shortly. But my goal is to identify multiple 100 mile radiuses that contain multiple items, with some potential overlap. I'm hoping that whatever I use is able to optimize in creating a minimal amount of 100 mile radiuses while capturing all the data.